# Since Vim 8.0, vim is outputting dotfiles into my directories

Tags: vim

I just upgraded to Vim for Windows 8.0, and despite the fact that I have this in my `_vimrc`:

```
set backupdir=C:\Windows\Temp
set backupskip=C:\Windows\Temp
set directory=C:\Windows\Temp
set writebackup
set noswapfile
```

... Vim still writes a file like `.myfile.txt.un~` to the same directory when I save the file I'm editing.  How can I get this to save somewhere else so as not to clutter up the directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I just realized that it's the undo functionality, and therefore I need to set the "undo dir".  Once I do this it stops write the files to the same directory:

```
set undodir=C:\Windows\Temp
```